# Listening to global IP address from termux

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, ip, termux

I want to make my android phone to work as server. So I wrote a node.js program to try to do this. The problem is - program cannot listen to global IP address, but works on locals.

So, my global IP was `176.59.20.7`. Here is my node.js code:

```js
const address = '176.59.20.7';
const port = 3000;
// code code code...
app.listen(port, address, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${address}:${port}`);
});
```

In the termux (terminal for android) I've got an error: `address not available 176.59.20.7:3000`

Even if I try to find my global IP from `ifconfig` in termux I cannot find it. But `IP Config` application from Play Market tells that my global IP is `176.59.20.7`.

So, how can I listen to my global IP? I mean, is there a way to use your smartphone as server?

Comment: you should try `0.0.0.0` instead of the `ip address`

Comment: And how can I access my "mobile server" if I listen to 0.0.0.0?